# How do I install a Python script in GIMP 2.7.2?

Tags: ubuntu, gimp

I am trying to install a python-fu script I downloaded from [registry.gimp.org](http://registry.gimp.org/node/18440). I downloaded it, changed its extension to .py and moved it to `~/.gimp-2.7/plug-ins`, but nothing happened. Am I doing something wrong?

I'm running Ubuntu Maverick (10.10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the .py file as executable? You can find more instructions on installing gimp plugins [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GIMP/Installing_Plugins#GNU.2FLinux).

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything.
In documentation for a python script I was trying to use, there was this cryptic comment "if GIMP has python support compiled in". How does one enable Python scripts in GIMP? How do you get GIMP with "python support compiled in"???